# automatically change file reference in index.html after minification in grunt

Tags: gruntjs

i am using grunt file in my project. in this file i want to add the process in which it will be able to replace the previous reference of minified file with the new one in index.html.

i am minifying the files with name and date/time e.g **mm_10/11/2016_5:00.min.js** after its minification the time will be changed **mm_10/11/2016_6:30.min.js**. but the index page is having the previous file i.e **mm_10/11/2016_5:00.min.js**. so i want to replace the **mm_10/11/2016_5:00.min.js** with **mm_10/11/2016_6:30.min.js**.
 kindly help me here

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this process dynamic you could consider configuring your grunt `Grunfile.js` to also generate the minified JavaScript file using [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify)

So firstly add that plugin to your package via the CLI if you don't already have it installed:

`$ npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev`

As the `Gruntfile.js` is a JavaScript file you can dynamically retrieve the current date/time properties for naming the new minified JavaScript file using the `new Date()` construct. This can be obtained using an IIFE (Immediately-invoked Function Expression) which assigns the resultant filename value to an object key, (E.g. `newJSFileName`), inside the function call `grunt.initConfig()`.

You can then use a Regular Expression in the `grunt-text-replace` task to find the the previous minified filename: E.g.

`/src=\"js\/mm_[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}.min.js\"/g`

The Regex above will match any instances of a string as follows.

`src="js/mm_10-12-2016-09-38-59.min.js"`

from the `<script>` tag within your `index.html` file. E.g.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mm_10-12-2016-09-38-59.min.js"></script>`

NOTE: The filename show here differs slightly from the naming convention show in my previous post, this time it also includes the seconds prior to the `.min.js` part. This will avoid issues if the `$ grunt` command is executed within less than a minute duration from when it was last run.

This seems to work well if you configue your `Guntfile.js` as follows:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        /* CREATE THE FILENAME STRING */
        newJsFileName: (function() {

            // Retrieve the current date and assign parts to variables
            var date = new Date(),
                day = date.getDate(),
                month = date.getMonth() + 1,
                year = date.getFullYear(),
                hour = date.getHours(),
                mins = date.getMinutes(),
                secs = date.getSeconds();

            // Prefix the day value with a zero when less than 10
            if (month < 10) {
                month = '0' + month;
            }

            // Prefix the day value with a zero when less than 10
            if (day < 10) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }

            // Prefix the hour value with a zero when less than 10
            if (hour < 10) {
                hour = '0' + hour;
            }

            // Prefix the minutes value with a zero when less than 10
            if (mins < 10) {
                mins = '0' + mins;
            }

            // Prefix the seconds value with a zero when less than 10
            if (secs < 10) {
                secs = '0' + secs;
            }

            // Concatenate the date properties to form the new
            // filename. E.g. mm_10-12-2016-12-52-05.min.js
            return 'mm_' + month + '-' + day + '-' + year + '-' + hour + '-' + mins + '-' + secs + '.min.js';
        }()),

        /* COPY THE HTML FILE */
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [{
                    expand: false,
                    src: 'src/index.html',
                    dest: 'dist/index.html'
                }]
            }
        },

        /* MINIFY THE JAVASCRIPT */
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    // NOTE: The source file here that we're looking for is already minified.
                    // E.g. 'src/js/*.min.js'
                    // however, you will probably want to replace this accordingly as minifying
                    // a file that is already minified seems unecessary.
                    'dist/js/<%= newJsFileName %>': 'src/js/*.min.js' // Destination : Source
                }
            }
        },

        /* REPLACE LINK TO CSS IN HTML FILE */
        replace: {
            javaScriptLink: {
                src: ['./dist/index.html'],
                overwrite: true,
                replacements: [{
                    // UTILIZE A REGULAR EXPRESSION TO FIND THE PREVIOUS MINIFIED FILE NAME STRING
                    // FROM WITHIN THE .HTML FILE
                    from: /src=\"js\/mm_[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}.min.js\"/g,
                    // THE NAME OF THE NEW MINIFIED FILE
                    to: 'src="js/<%= newJsFileName %>"'
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'copy',
        'uglify',
        'replace:javaScriptLink'
    ]);

};
```

Before running the `$ grunt` command with the configuration shown above you will need to make sure that your `index.html` has the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag set to use the naming convention that includes the additional seconds attribute, otherwise the Regex defined in the `Gruntfile.js` will not work. E.g.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mm_10-12-2016-09-38`**-59**`.min.js"></script>`

Also, ensure your JavaScript file is named accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it worked. thank you so much...i was blank before ypur help. thanks for help